# Class definition within namespace goes out to lunch, never returns

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the following:

```
namespace A {
 /* Class prototype */
 class B {
  private:
   type member_1;
  public:
   return_type member_2( arguments );
 };
}
```

Later on (in another file that includes the file with the above block), I do the following:

```
namespace A {
 /* Function prototype */
 B function_name( arguments ); /* error on this line */
}
```

And I get the error: `'A' does not name a type`

I've even tried `A::B function_name( arguments );`, but alas, I got the same error.

Comment: Can you provide a more formal definition of "later on"?

Comment: You might want to use the  format as code button in the question editor. It's the one with { } on it

Comment: "later on" is in another file that includes the file with the first block of code.

Comment: Make sure that the file where B is declared does not include the second file (i.e the files include each other). Need more information to know what is happening.

Comment: Ahh. That was it. The files were both including each other. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be really helpful if you showed us the actual code that doesn't work.

From the code you have provided and the error I have a couple guesses:

- You reused `A` as a class or variable.
- There's broken code *before* the `namespace A` in "later".
- You're passing parameters that you aren't showing and they're declared with unknown types.
- "Later" is actually a header file, and the two files have a circular dependency on each other.